# Can contextmenu call onAppear every time?

Tags: macos, swiftui, contextmenu

when user right click showing the `contextMenu` **every time**, before the menu button is clicked, the app needs to do something. I tried to set the action within `onAppear`, but  `onAppear`is only called once. Is there any other way to detect every display of `contextMenu`? Thanks.

```
var body: some View {

    Text("Hello, world!")   
        .contextMenu {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
            
                }) {
                    Text("Normal Colors")
                }
       
                Button(action: {
            
                }) {
                    Text("Inverted Colors")
                }

            }.onAppear {
                // do something before press the button
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI: Notification when .contextMenu is dismissed (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72714335/swiftui-notification-when-contextmenu-is-dismissed-ios)

Answer (score -1):

This is a close approximation:

```
    @GestureState var isDetectingLongPress = false

    var longPress: some Gesture {
        LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.1)
            .updating($isDetectingLongPress) { currentState, gestureState,
                    transaction in
                print("contextMenu appeared")
            }
    }

    var body: some View {

        Text("Hello, world!")
            .contextMenu {
                VStack {
                    Button(action: {
                
                    }) {
                        Text("Normal Colors")
                    }
           
                    Button(action: {
                
                    }) {
                        Text("Inverted Colors")
                    }
                }
            }
            .gesture(longPress)
   }
```

I am not sure of your use case, so I don't know whether this is good enough. The `LongPressGesture` will always fire before the `contextMenu` activates, and it is sequential. The contextMenu doesn't start its timer until the `LongPressGesture` duration has been reached. The benefits are it always fires. The drawback, it may fire, and the user changes their mind and stops the gesture before the menu fires.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. Every click calls `longPress` immediately even duration is set to 3 seconds, and it blocks the contextMenu showing up.

Comment: I wasn't seeing an immediate `longPress` activation, but I agree that it blocks the `contextMenu` until the `longPress` duration has run. I threw it out there in case it would work.

Comment: I said `longPress' meant to represent gesture action.